# Where to store dataset when creating neural network models and using github?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science-model

I have been recommended to use GitHub for all my coding projects as it is a great way to demonstrate to employers what you have been working on as well as just sharing anything you have created that might be useful to others. So I am storing my code for Neural Network Models I am working in a GitHub repository but I am not sure when I download a data set to run a test with where I should download that too? Inside or outside the git repository?

Sorry if this is a dumb question but new to this. I can imagine arguments for either answer. Mainly size being too big or the results being easily reproducible.

Comment: Why do you not just use Kaggle? They are great for storing datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dataset isn't too large, you may add datasets on GitHub itself. Generally project datasets aren't large, but again, I can't be sure as you haven't mentioned any approximate size. But if it is large, you may refer to data source in your **[ReadMe](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/README.md)** or within your `.py` file as an external hyperlink.

For example, save dataset on *Google Drive* & turn on *Viewable* option by generating shareable URL. Now that generated link can be refered to in your *ReadMe* file as something like: *"[Kindly refer this external link to access dataset](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data)"*. Alternatively, you may also read data directly within your `.py` file from that generated link, and any project reviewer would notice that external link being used to read dataset.

Hope that answers your query!

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload dataset inside repository
2. Upload on drive and attach the link, change the sharing settings to visible to all
3. Directly provide source link if available